# Solve $3x³ + 3y³ + 2x² - 32 = 0$, $4x² + 2 = 0$ and $10y² + 2x² + 12 = 12x³$.

Tags: integration, derivatives, complex-numbers

Hi my friend asked this to me, i'm not good at math.
$$3x³ + 3y³ + 2x² - 32 = 0$$
$$4x² + 2 = 0$$
$$10y² + 2x² + 12 = 12x³$$

---

remove **2x²**
$$2x² = -1$$
$$3x³ + 3y³ - 1 - 32 = 0$$
$$10y² - 1 + 12 = 12x³$$

---

done cannot finish it

Comment: Please add what how you have tried to solve the question. Without it, you wont receive any responses.

Comment: Are these three separate problems?

Comment: @Apurv i don't know what is that. already forgot my math in high school bro.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork no, it's related sir

Comment: @JosuaMarcelChrisano, Then better not post on this site. Try Yahoo!answers, WikiAnswers or Quora.

Comment: @Apurv wait i will working on that first

Comment: One tip  can be  given. Number of equations should be same as number of variables to be solved for. So , delete one of three equations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.
$$3x³ + 3y³ + 2x² - 32 = 0$$

We can write:

$$y=\frac{\left(\sqrt{=3x^3-2x^2+32}\right)^\frac{1}{3}}{\left(\sqrt{3}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}}$$
$$\frac{\left(\sqrt{3x^3-2x^2+32}\right)^\frac{1}{3}}{\left(\sqrt{3}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}}=0$$

Gives us (real):

$$x=2$$

Gives us (complex):

$$x=-\frac{4}{3}i\left(\sqrt{2}-i\right)$$

Or:

$$x=\frac{4}{3}i\left(\sqrt{2}+i\right)$$

2.
$$4x² + 2 = 0$$
$$4x^2=-2$$
$$x^2=-\frac{1}{2}$$

Gives us (Complex):

$$x=-\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}$$
$$x=\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}$$

3.
$$10y² + 2x² + 12 = 12x³$$

Gives us:

$$6x^3-x^2=6$$

Real solution:

$$\frac{1}{18}\left(1+\left(\sqrt{2917-54\sqrt{2918}}\right)^\frac{1}{3}+\left(\sqrt{2917+54\sqrt{2918}}\right)^\frac{1}{3}\right)$$